# Find $x$ for $3^x = 5/3$ Why my answer is wrong?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

$3^x = 5/3$

$e^{\ln 3^x} = 5/3$

$e^{x \ln 3}=5/3$

$e^x \times e^{\ln 3} = 5/3$

$e^x \times 3 = 5/3$

$e^x = 5/9$

$x = \ln(5/9)$

Comment: It seems to be that you think that $\;x=\ln 3^x\;$ . This is false. What is true is either $$x=\log_33^x\;,\;\;\text{or else}\;\; x=\ln e^x$$

Comment: $e^{ab}$ is NOT equal to $e^ae^b$!

Comment: The left side term of the first equal is $3^x$. However the right side term is not $\frac{5}{3}$. Your equation should be $e^{x ln 3}=\frac{5}{3}$ instead. However, this particular equation would solve easier if you applied $log_3$ to both sides.

Comment: using x = e^(ln x) thus 3^x = e^(ln 3^x) why this is wrong?

Comment: That is not wrong. Wrong is the right side of equal: “ 5/3 e^(xln3)”, when it should be jus $\frac{5}{3}$.

Comment: $e^x\times e^{\ln 3} = e^{x + \ln 3}$

Comment: Thank you. I was watching  MindYourDecisions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWPIQf4HaW0 and I cant find why my answer is wrong. Thank you. now I understand why i was wrong

Answer (score 1):

We know that $a^x = e^{x \ln a}$

thus $3^x = e^{x \ln 3} = 5/3$

applying $\ln$ to both sides, we get $x \ln 3 = \ln (5/3) = \ln(5) - \ln(3)$

The rest is straightforward algebra:

$$x \ln 3 + \ln 3 - \ln 5 = 0$$
$$(x+1) \ln 3  = \ln 5$$
$$x + 1 = \ln 5 / \ln 3$$
$$x = \frac{\ln 5}{\ln 3} - 1$$

Answer (score 0):

$3^x=\frac{5}{3}\Leftrightarrow e^{x ln 3}=\frac{5}{3}$; as you see you have a mistake right after the first equal sign.

Try instead $$3^x=\frac{5}{3}|\log_3 \Leftrightarrow \log_3(3^x)=\log_3\left( \frac{5}{3}\right )$$

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that $e^{x\ln 3}\neq e^x\times e^{\ln 3}$. In general $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c\neq a^ba^c$.